# Dimension too large for a simple 3D picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, intersections

I created this simple 3D box.  Everything looks as expected, but I keep getting error

```
Dimension too large.
```

Is there any way to avoid it?[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\def\anga{22.5}
\def\angb{-135}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={({-sin(\angb)*1cm},{cos(\angb)*sin(\anga)*1cm})},y={({-cos(\angb)*1cm},{-sin(\angb)*sin(\anga)*1cm})},z={(0cm,{cos(\anga)*1cm})},scale=0.4]

\draw (10,7.5,0) -- (0,7.5,0) -- (0,0,0) -- (10,0,0) -- cycle;
\path[name path=above,blue]  (0,0,0) -- (10,0,0) -- (10,7.5,0);
\path[name path=below,red] (10,7.5,-1.5) -- (0,7.5,-1.5) -- (0,0,-1.5);
\draw[name intersections={of=above and below}] (intersection-1) -- (0,7.5,-1.5) -- (intersection-2);
\draw (0,0,0) -- (0,0,-1.5) -- (10,0,-1.5) -- (10,7.5,-1.5) -- (10,7.5,0) (10,0,-1.5) -- (10,0,0) (0,7.5,-1.5) -- (0,7.5,0);
\draw[densely dashed] (intersection-1) -- (0,0,-1.5) (intersection-2) -- (10,7.5,-1.5);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't help you with why, but if you change the scale to 0.399 it gets rid of the error. Somebody much better than I am might be able to explain.

Comment: @PaulA You are right...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a strange thing. I suspect the following:

Both your paths contain two segments:

- the one along the *x* axis and
- the one along the *y* axis.

That means that each path contains segments that are parallel to segments of the other path. These will never intersect and even though the library does have some checks against trying to calculate intersections between parallel lines
it looks like – due to the imprecision of TeX – in your specific case this check fails or these segments aren't strictly parallel anymore. Using `scale=0.3999` or `4.01` will changes the numbers ever so slightly that the library's check works again or the lines will be correctly flagged as parallel again.

I'll have two work-arounds for you:

1. Constructing four paths and only finding the intersections between those that aren't (almost) parallel:

   ```
    \path[name path=above1,blue] (0,0,0) -- (10,0,0);
    \path[name path=above2,blue] (10,0,0) -- (10,7.5,0);
    \path[name path=below1,red] (0,7.5,-1.5) -- (0,0,-1.5);
    \path[name path=below2,red] (10,7.5,-1.5) -- (0,7.5,-1.5);
    \draw[name intersections={of=above1 and below1, by=i1},
          name intersections={of=above2 and below2, by=i2}]
          (i1) -- (0,7.5,-1.5) -- (i2);
   ```
2. Using the `intersection cs` or its implicit version `intersection of` (this is not documented anymore in the manual and it can only find intersections between [lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(geometry)) – and *not* line segments – defined by two points on the lines and circular nodes).

   ```
    \coordinate (intersection-1)
      at (intersection of 0,0,0--10,0,0 and 0,0,-1.5--0,10,-1.5)
     coordinate (intersection-2)
      at (intersection of 10,7.5,0--10,0,0 and 10,7.5,-1.5--0,7.5,-1.5);
   ```

   This doesn't require the `intersections` library but it needs the `calc` library when circular nodes are involved.

   By the way,

   ```
    \path (intersection of 0,0--0,1 and 1,0--1.00001,1);
   ```

   triggers a `Dimension too large.` error as well since its intersection lies very far away.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\tikzset{
  Pyg cs/.style 2 args={
    x={({-sin(#2)*1cm},{cos(#2)*sin(#1)*1cm})},
    y={({-cos(#2)*1cm},{-sin(#2)*sin(#1)*1cm})},
    z={(0cm,{cos(#1)*1cm})}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[Pyg cs={22.5}{-135}, scale=0.4]
\draw (10,7.5,0) -- (0,7.5,0) -- (0,0,0) -- (10,0,0) -- cycle;
\path[name path=above1,blue] (0,0,0) -- (10,0,0);
\path[name path=above2,blue] (10,0,0) -- (10,7.5,0);
\path[name path=below1,red] (0,7.5,-1.5) -- (0,0,-1.5);
\path[name path=below2,red] (10,7.5,-1.5) -- (0,7.5,-1.5);
\draw[name intersections={of=above1 and below1, by=i1},
      name intersections={of=above2 and below2, by=i2}]
      (i1) -- (0,7.5,-1.5) -- (i2);
\draw (0,0,0) -- (0,0,-1.5) -- (10,0,-1.5) -- (10,7.5,-1.5) -- (10,7.5,0)
      (10,0,-1.5) -- (10,0,0) (0,7.5,-1.5) -- (0,7.5,0);
\draw[densely dashed] (i1) -- (0,0,-1.5) (i2) -- (10,7.5,-1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[Pyg cs={22.5}{-135}, scale=0.4]
\draw (10,7.5,0) -- (0,7.5,0) -- (0,0,0) -- (10,0,0) -- cycle;
\coordinate (intersection-1)
  at (intersection of 0,0,0--10,0,0 and 0,0,-1.5--0,10,-1.5)
 coordinate (intersection-2)
  at (intersection of 10,7.5,0--10,0,0 and 10,7.5,-1.5--0,7.5,-1.5);
\draw (intersection-1) -- (0,7.5,-1.5) -- (intersection-2)
      (0,0,0) -- (0,0,-1.5) -- (10,0,-1.5) -- (10,7.5,-1.5) -- (10,7.5,0)
      (10,0,-1.5) -- (10,0,0) (0,7.5,-1.5) -- (0,7.5,0);
\draw[densely dashed] (intersection-1) -- (0,0,-1.5)
                      (intersection-2) -- (10,7.5,-1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
% \tikz\path(intersection of 0,0--0,1 and 1,0--1.00001,1);
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was very clear and consistent answer.  I think I will go with 1, I try to avoid undocumented stuff.

Comment: @Pygmalion No problem. Lastly, I'd recommend using named coordinates so that you don't have to specify the numbers again and again. `\foreach \t/\u in {bottom/-1.5, top/0} \coordinate (\t-00) at (0,0,\u) coordinate (\t-x0) at (10,0,\u) coordinate (\t-0y) at (0,7.5,\u) coordinate (\t-xy) at (10,7.5,\u);` gives you eight neatly named coordinates you can use over and over again. (And even `10` and `7.5` don't need to be hard-coded.)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [3dtools](https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3dtools}%https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[3d/install view={phi=140,theta=70},line cap=butt,line join=round,c/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt},
        declare function={a=4;b=3;c=.5;}] 
\path (0,0,0) coordinate (A)
(a,0,0) coordinate (B)
(a,b,0) coordinate (C)
(0,b,0) coordinate (D)
(0,0,c) coordinate (A')
(a,0,c) coordinate (B')
(a,b,c) coordinate (C')
(0,b,c) coordinate (D')
;
    %\path foreach \p/\g in {A/180,B/-90,C/0,D/90,A'/180,B'/-90,C'/0,D'/90}
%{(\p)node[c]{}+(\g:2.5mm) node{$\p$}};
\draw[3d/visible] (A') -- (B') -- (C') -- (D') --cycle (A) -- (A');
\path[save named path=rec1]
(B) -- (B') -- (C') -- (C) --cycle; 
\path[save named path=rec2]
(C) -- (C') -- (D') -- (D) --cycle;
\path[save named path=lBA]
(B) -- (A); 
\path[save named path=lDA]
(D) -- (A);
\tikzset{3d/draw ordered paths={lBA,rec1}}
\tikzset{3d/draw ordered paths={lDA,rec2}}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]